# Navigation Architecture Component singleTask or singleInstance in back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-sdk-tools, android-jetpack

I have an BottomNavigationView and I would like to use it to navigate between three or four different fragments. If I instantiated one of the fragment I don't want do it again for same fragment I just want to reuse it.
NavOptions class providing launchSingleTop property to avoid to create new instance if that kind of instance already on top of the back stack. But how about singleTask or singleInstance option for back stack of fragments in navigation controller? If I no need to create new instance of fragment if it's already in the back stack and I just want to bring it on top? How to achieve this with Navigation Architecture Component of Jetpack?

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Comment: @JashanPJ no I just used this solution https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/navigation-keep-fragment-sample

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this problem and I finally found a solution. You can use `popUpTo` to achieve it.

So for example, you have fragment Home, Login, and Register.

From fragment Home, you navigate to Login, and then to Register, and to Login again. To prevent duplicate Login fragment, you should set `popUpTo="@id/login_fragment"` to the action.

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_navigation_register_to_navigation_login"
    app:destination="@id/navigation_login"
    app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_login" />
```

Stack visualization:

```
             Register
             ____
Login  ==>   Login   ==>   Login
____         ____          ____
Home         Home          Home
```